# How to create an organisation in Black Duck Open Hub?

Tags: community

Black Duck Open Hub provides analytics for Open Source projects, and has entries for organisations, found at https://www.openhub.net/explore/orgs , allowing a collection of projects and interesting analytics of affiliated and non-affiliated contributors to those projects, and also analytics of what non-org projects those contributors collectively also contribute to.

However I can not find the process to create an organisation.

There was a thread in the old forum system where people could ask for an org to be created, and occasionally someone at Black Duck would do a batch of them.

The new forum system at https://community.synopsys.com/s/black-duck-open-hub seems dead and I don't see a similar thread.

Answer (score 3):

I do see your recent 31st October post on the OpenHub forum. The usual response time from this team is 1-2 working days. 31st being a Sunday, you should expect a response by today.

Comment: Hi Alex, I look forward to learning the new process.

Comment: The org was created by Alex , after providing a list of relevant repos and the desired org name at https://community.synopsys.com/s/question/0D52H00005jZvm1SAC/how-do-we-create-an-organisation .  Alex, are their any other details that should be provided.  Perhaps you want to create another answer which describes the ideal forum post which will be actioned, then I can accept that as the answer.